# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received '' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

While I am try to build react app then it show this error

node:internal/errors:465
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received ''
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1000:11)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at getConfigAsObject (C:\Users\syam.das\Desktop\5\doe-web\node_modules@craco\craco\lib\config.js:46:20)
at loadCracoConfigAsync (C:\Users\syam.das\Desktop\5\doe-web\node_modules@craco\craco\lib\config.js:69:34)
at Object. (C:\Users\syam.das\Desktop\5\doe-web\node_modules@craco\craco\scripts\start.js:22:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

```
        const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const { getArgs } = require("./args");
    const { log } = require("./logger");
    const { isString } = require("./utils");

    const projectRoot = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
    const packageJsonPath = path.join(projectRoot, "package.json");

    log("Project root path resolved to: ", projectRoot);

    let configFilePath = "";

    const configFilenames = ["craco.config.js", ".cracorc.js", ".cracorc"];

    const args = getArgs();

    if (args.config.isProvided) {
        configFilePath = path.resolve(projectRoot, args.config.value);
    } else {
        const package = require(packageJsonPath);

        if (package.cracoConfig) {
            if (!isString(package.cracoConfig)) {
                throw new Error("craco: 'cracoConfig' value must be a string.");
            }

            configFilePath = path.resolve(projectRoot, package.cracoConfig);
        } else {
            for (const filename of configFilenames) {
                const filePath = path.join(projectRoot, filename);

                if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
                    configFilePath = filePath;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    log("Config file path resolved to: ", configFilePath);

    module.exports = {
        projectRoot,
        packageJsonPath,
        configFilePath
    };
```

Comment: Looks like you need to debug your Craco config file.

Comment: Can you please help me to debug Carco config file. Please guide me the steps to do that

Comment: Hi @Andi I just type yarn add @craco/craco in console and now its working fine. Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just type `yarn add @craco/craco` in console and now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `require("")` in your project but you are missing the argument of the `require` function so you receive this err `"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received ''";`

In you code you are emptying the `require` function like this

```
const userProfile=require("");
```

its wrong:
Use it like this:

```
const profileSchema=require("../../models/profile/profileSchema");
```